# How to add sidebar icon on osx version 10.10 and 10.11

Tags: macos, sidebar

I am tring to add a custom icon to sidebar (favorites).
I tried the next link - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Finder.html 
But I cannt see any change.
I also tryed to add folder with objective c:

```
LSSharedFileListRef favoriteList = NULL;
CFStringRef urlStringRef = NULL;
CFURLRef url = NULL;
IconRef icon = NULL;
CFStringRef displayName = NULL;
LSSharedFileListItemRef item = NULL;
favoriteList = LSSharedFileListCreate(NULL, kLSSharedFileListFavoriteItems, NULL);
urlStringRef = CFStringCreateWithCString(NULL, (path.toUtf8().data()), kCFStringEncodingUTF8 );
url = CFURLCreateWithFileSystemPath(NULL, urlStringRef , kCFURLPOSIXPathStyle, NULL);
std::string str = "/Users/mac-templates/Package_Insert.icns";
FSPathMakeRef((const UInt8*) str.c_str(), &fsRef, &isDirectory);
RegisterIconRefFromFSRef(NULL, NULL, &fsRef, &icon);
displayName = CFStringCreateWithCString(NULL, FAVORITES_OSX_DISPLAY_NAME, kCFStringEncodingUTF8 );
item = LSSharedFileListInsertItemURL(favoriteList, kLSSharedFileListItemBeforeFirst, displayName, icon, url, NULL, NULL);
```

After running the bellow code, I can see the new folder in the sidebar but the icon is the standard folder icon.
it means command 'kLSSharedFileListItemBeforeFirst' works partially, it's add the folder to the sidebar but without icon.

Has someone added icon to the sidebar?

Thx